# Ebay REST API - application token for listing products and updating inventory

Tags: .net, rest, oauth, ebay-api

I'd like to create a service in my application, which creates products listing and updates inventory on ebay using the data in my database. In my understanding you are able to request an oauth application token with using client ID and client secret ([ebay](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/gen-app-token.html)) and this way you can obtain a working token without popping up a window to login to your (or user) ebay account and ask for permission. However application tokens are really limited, you cannot ask for a scope for changing products. So you need a user token ([ebay)](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/gen-user-token.html) but you are not able to obtain one without showing the ebay login screen to grant permission. Even if I implement the way how it is described, the token expires in 8 hours, so you have to go through the same procedure if you want to do something the other day, or you keep refreshing the token in the background.

**So my question: Is there a way to use ebay's new REST api without popping up the login screen of ebay to grant access?**

**Second question: In my understanding using the old, xml-based *trading api* involves the same problem, is that right?**

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer **NO**. You will **never** be able to perform API operations on eBay that involve a seller's account without that seller granting permission to your app. This permission must be granted by the seller logging into their eBay account. This has also been true for the Trading API for many years.

Comment: I understand this, but do you have to grant the permission every single time, when you want to access your ebay account from your application? I mean this sound illogical, I think i just don't know how to do this properly even after reading through their documentation. Do you have a hint here?

Comment: A user token is shorted lived but you also get a refresh token that lasts for a few months. This refresh token can be used to get a new user token with requiring the user to log into their eBay account. More information is given at http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/gen-user-token.html#Updating

Comment: @DavidT.Sadler The link is dead

Comment: @Fo. Updated link https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/rest/ebay-rest/content/oauth-gen-user-token.html#Updating